# Xubuntu 22.04 crashing on first reboot

Tags: xubuntu, 22.04

I'm trying to install Xubuntu 22.04 from an USB stick on a new HDD.

I tried once. The installation process went smoothly until I get prompted to restart. After pressing the "Restart now" button, I get a black screen with Xubuntu logo and it stayed that way until I finally forced restart something like 20 minutes later.

I tried booting on Xubuntu and it worked, but given what happened I assumed it didn't install correctly. So I tried the process again and now I'm seeing the exact same thing : frozen black screen with Xubuntu logo.

According to the guide I was following I should be prompted to remove my USB drive and press enter to complete the reboot but it doesn't happen.

Thank you for your time.

EDIT : The suggested question doesn't relate to my issue as I don't get a freeze at booting, I get it when shuting down.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Did you try pressing Enter at that screen? Perhaps just the text telling you to do so is missing?

Comment: I didn't, instead I pressed f1 as seen on other topics, it shut down. It seems to boot normally, but I have no idea if the install is clean.

Comment: There is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/casper/+bug/1944519) which causes the eject media (remove USB) message to not appear on some hardware.. Do **not** pull the USB/media out early; just wait until the machine responds to ENTER being pressed (ie. it'll reboot on pressing ENTER when pressed at the correct time; you can safely eject media/USB quickly as machine reboots without harm)

Comment: In my experience the best way is to shut down, remove the USB device, and start the computer.

Comment: I faced the same issue and @guiverc's suggestion worked for me.